# How to replace low res image reference at end of URL string with the higher res image reference available

Tags: java, android, split, android-image

From an API I'm getting a thumbnail image from the URL string similar to this format:
https://website.com/05b8a817448d0e2/0_167_3000_1799/500.jpg. However, it looks very blotchy for android app development.

There is no high-res image available from the API. However, I have discovered that by changing the end of the URL, the images exist at 1000px and even 2000px.

I want to change the URL string to the higher res version that exists at the same location with the improved suffix:
https://website.com/05b8a817448d0e2/0_167_3000_1799/1000.jpg

**Extra requirements:**

- Rarely the API gives different sizes other than 500, like 1000 or 250
- In rare cases it ends with .png instead of .jpg (possibly even other formats)
- In rare cases the image doesn't exist at a higher res and should be left alone

So the solution needs to be quite a lot more robust that my current coding capabilities.

This is my code block in Android Studio which works fine, but doesn't cover the extra requirements. I have only been coding in Java and Android Studio a few months so there may be some issues with it:

```
 /**
 * Load an image from a URL and return a {@link Bitmap}
 *
 * @param url string of the URL link to the image
 * @return Bitmap of the image
 */
private static Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    String newUrlString = url;

    try {
        // Change 500px image to 1000px image
        URL oldUrl = new URL(url);
        if (url.endsWith("500.jpg")) {
            newUrlString = oldUrl.toString().replaceFirst("500.jpg", "1000.jpg");
        }

        InputStream inputStream = new URL(newUrlString).openStream();
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following:

```
protected class ImageLoader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            String originalUrl = urls[0];
            String url = urls[0].replaceFirst("/500.", "/1000.");
            try {
                InputStream inputStream = new URL(url).openStream();
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                try {
                    InputStream inputStream = new URL(originalUrl).openStream();
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                } catch (Exception ignored) {
                }
            }
            return bitmap;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            //do whatever you want with the result.
            if(bitmap!=null)
            image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
```

What I did here, is that I created an AsyncTask (since your original code will throw `NetworkOnMainThreadException` ) called **ImageLoader**. It will handle requesting the image url; if it fails to get the 1000px version, it will failover to the 500px version of the image.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Mohammad! On this course, I'm not allowed to use libraries unless they are totally unrelated to the coursework that was covered. Once the course is over I will use Picasso for my apps that handle downloaded images.

Comment: ok, I've updated my code accordingly. note that you should not to do a network call over main thread. Instead, use multi threading, for example putting the code that loads the urls inside an **asynctask** or a **service** for example

Comment: Thank you! I have it at the bottom of my QueryUtils.java file. I'm wondering how to tackle basically any size the original url throws at me, and change it to 1000. I have come across a few that were 800, 250 and other random numbers. So cant do a search and replace for 500 with 1000. So in other words, if anySize < 1000 then anySize == 1000. I just dont know how to extract it like that.

Comment: try this

        `String url = "http://mywebsite.com/2309.jpg";`
        `String url_1000 = url.replace(url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/")),"/1000.jpg");`

Comment: Thanks this works beautifully! Since I already had it in my QueryUtils.java class and not the main thread, I used the code you provided in the middle and then updated it according to your recent comment. I couldn't upvote your answer because I don't have enough rep points but can give you the accepted answer!!